# Проблема с маской для input

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputmask

Проблема с input и библиотекой для маски на input [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

1) Мне нужно удалить из телефона если его печатают с число 7 или 8 щас работает нормально. Но проблема возникает когда вставляют телефон из буфера обмена, то работает не корректно. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить или решить с помощью другого плагина.

Фаил js

```
$(function(){
    $('#js-phone').mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");

    $('#js-phone').on('keyup', function(event) {
       let $this = $(this).val()    ;
       let phone = '';
       if($this[5] == '9') {
          if($this[4] == '8' || $this[4] == '7') {
            phone = $this.slice(0,4) + $this.slice(5);
            $(this).val(phone);
          }
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного костыльно, но работает, [демка](http://vpsvds.ru/downloads/demo.html)

```
$(function(){

    $('#js-phone').mask("+7 (999) 999-99-999");

    $('#js-phone').on('keyup', function(event) {
    reserveVal = $(this).cleanVal();
    phone = $(this).cleanVal().slice(0,10);
    $(this).val($(this).masked(phone));
       if($(this).cleanVal()[1] == '9') {
          if($(this).cleanVal()[0] == '8' || $(this).cleanVal()[0] == '7') {
            phone = reserveVal.slice(1);
            $(this).val($(this).masked(phone)); 
          }
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Всё равно не работает, если вставлять номер телефона с помощью ctrl+v

Comment: Поправил свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо работает, а возможно сделать чтобы всегда было в начале +7(_ и печатать начинаешь сразу от _

Comment: Можно самому input в форме задать `value="+7 ("` [демо](http://vpsvds.ru/downloads/demo2.html). Если работает, то отметьте ответ правильным, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое.